# Search function in c#

Tags: asp.net, seo, search-engine

I am trying to create a search page which searches the user given input against the meta data in the html files and shows the results accordingly, in short a simple search via metadata.

So far i have succeeded in getting the meta tags of the files. but unable to think any further how to get the relative comparison of the user given string and the meta data and sort the links according to the highest relevancy.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Create search engine for site in asp .net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878914/create-search-engine-for-site-in-asp-net-c/5879035#5879035)