# Create search engine for site in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine

Newbie alert!

ASP .net | C# | VS2008 | MS SQL server 2008 R2 Express

I have a database with file names, file paths and file category. I have lots of static pages in the website also. I want to develop a custom search engine (since I am not allowed to use other 3rd party tools - basically they want me to reinvent the wheel).

When the user searches for something, it should search the file names and also the content of the static pages. File names can be searched straightforward from  the database(did it). The static pages are SEO friendly with headers,etc.

How do I go about indexing the static pages in the website? How to create the search index after some pages are added in future? Are there functions like curl in php that can be used in ASP.net C#?

Also I heard about full text search. Any links on how to query the full text database?

P.S: Newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure your pages won't change at all in near future, look up SQL full text indexing, which should serve most purposes. But if you need to scale up going forward.You should look at [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (built using Lucene) - it offers a RESTful interface for integrating into .NET or whatever platform you prefer. It offers all the goodies could ask for such as faceting without concern for compatibility Java, .NET versions etc.

You can easily integrate Solr into your .NET app using [1](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/)

Comment: thanks! How do I use SQL full text indexing for static webpages? The content is hardcoded in the pages.

Comment: also how to read the HTML pages? any file handlers available?

Comment: Not sure if you can import the content using SQL Server's import/export utility. If not, you can write up something quite easily using many of the existing HTML Parsers available. I'd recommend http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use cURL for pHP.
Just use the IO functions to manipulate the list of files in the directory (web) and get their content and store them in the database for future search. From the text you can retrieve the page title, meta tags too with Regular expressions.

Let me know if you need code for this if the logic suitable for you.